# Turn off migrations in Django

Tags: django, database-migration

This is driving me crazy. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. I'm developing a Django project, and every so often I need to change something to better fit with the rest.

Up to Django 1.6, there was no problem. Whenever I wanted to change some models, fields, whatever, I did so and ran syncdb. But now, with migrations, syncdb is just an alias for migrate, and it tries too hard to be smart. Did you rename this field? Did you remove that field? You MUST specify a default... What do you care, those are just test data. Nuke them and I'll enter new ones. And despite my honest answers, I still get "column doesn't exist", "numeric cannot be cast as hstore", "Decimal is not JSON serializable" and other wonders. I guess once the project goes into production, migrations will surely be of much help. But while I'm developing it, please spare me. :-/

I tried deleting `myapp/migrations` directory. I tried dropping `django_migrations` table from psql. I tried `manage startapp myapp` again. I tried `manage flush`. It works temporarily, but after a while, the project still somehow "remembers" what was in the models previously, and throws a tantrum.

Please, is there any normal way to say "just drop all tables, reset all data, read models.py, and recreate the database from that"? The way syncdb used to work.

Answer (score 0):

To make changes in existing database you must use migrations.

If you make changes in models and don't want to use migrations, you have two ways:

1. add this changes to db manually
2. DROP database and create it again

`manage flush` DOES NOT clear database and drop tables, it clear only data and returns DB to state after syncdb.

You should write makefile, which will drop database and create it again, then syncdb.

UPD:
you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlclear-app-label-app-label too

Comment: 1 goes againist the DRY. 2 (with makefile automation) seems doable, but permissions are complicated and I'll probably have to type a lot of passwords when I'm recreating the database. Besides, that step really seems like something that shouldn't be done approximately three times a day. :-P So... it seems my hunch was right, there really is no way to do it simply anymore. I think this will alienate many people from Django. :-( And no, I cannot use sqlclear. They shut down that road too. `App myapp has migrations. You cannot use sqlclear when an app has migrations.` Shame.